# XML parsing into a custom dialog

Tags: android, xml, parsing, dialog, xml-parsing

Is it possible to parse XML retrieved from a web address into a custom dialog?

Say I press a marker/button, I want it to display a custom dialog in which my xml has parsed and is diplayed.

Attempting this I get the following error in logcat:

'overlay is not ready to queue buffers'

Comment: There are xml parser jars I haven't found one that is thread safe for android. If it is a real simple and repetitive type of parser that regex can solve you can try regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this I Instead used a class with the theme of a dialog. Set custom width, height, and layout, so on. This allowed me to parse the xml to this class.

Hope it helps someone